# C++ array in structure access

Tags: c++

I have this structure in c++:

```
struct Vertex_2 {
    GLdouble position[3];
};
```

I am trying to access the array inside of it like this:

```
Vertex_2.position[0] = //something;
Vertex_2.position[1] = //something;
....
...
..
```

when I compile it I get this:

```
error: expected unqualified-id before ‘.’ token
```

why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create an instance of the `struct` before using the members thereof.

```
Vertex_2 v; // v is an *instance* of the *struct* Vertex_2
v.position[0] = //something;
v.position[1] = //something;
...
```

Think of `Vertex_2` as a description of what all `Vertex_2`'s should look like (but it is not, itself, a `Vertex_2`). Then you have to actually create a `Vertex_2`, by doing `Vertex_2 name;`. In the example, we used the name `v` instead of `name`, but you can name the instance whatever you want. Then you can access the member variables of that instance through the name with a dot (`.`), like you tried to do before.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a variable of your class, you only defined a type.

```
struct Vertex_2 {
    GLdouble position[3];
} varVertex_2; // <-- now you have an instance of the struct


varVertex_2.position[0] = //something;
varVertex_2.position[1] = //something;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to access struct type not the actual struct. Try:

```
struct Vertex_2 {
    GLdouble position[3];
} myVertex;

myVertex.position[0] = //something;
myVertex.position[1] = //something;
```